# Android Studio error=2

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to import a project in Android Studio. It works fine on an Ubuntu machine while I am having windows 10. 
The error is:

> Error:CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I have implemented all the changes which showed on my google search like changing the java versions etc. But still cannot find a solution.

Please guide me through the steps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351122/2826147

Comment: I already said that I have implemented all the possible solutions visible

Comment: than please mention links in questions otherwise how can we know.

Comment: Did you solve this?