# Android Error : java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ioexception

I am getting the following error while building one e-commerce application.

It is Building Successfully but when I try to run this application, Giving me error as following:

[image]

My **build.gradle** having following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '27.1.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.+'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.12.0'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
}
```

I don't know where is a problem, is there anyone who knows about this?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874546/createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-android-studio

Comment: Is NDK updated?

Comment: I think problem is that gradle can't find sdk or ndk location. Are your paths correct?

Comment: All errors are mips related. Have you tried to explicitly set the list of wanted abis and leave mips out? This should be possible using the gradle entry `abiFilters`.

Comment: please add both `build.gradle` files

Answer (score 1):

**Link Gradle to your native library** by providing a path to your CMake or ndk-build script file. Gradle uses the build script to import source code into your Android Studio project and package your native library (the SO file) into the APK.

If your existing project uses the deprecated ndkCompile tool, you should open your **build.properties** file and remove the following line of code before configuring Gradle to use CMake or ndk-build:

```
// Remove this line
android.useDeprecatedNdk = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your ndk is corrupted or damaged.

If i was you, I would try

1. Update or try delete old ndk and download latest ndk
2. Also i think you are running old Android Studio, why don't you update your Android Studio and Gralde version, i always love when new stable Android Studio comes because **android update is one man army to unknown bugs**. :)